# Decompiling windows photo viewer

Tags: dll, .net

I'm trying to decompile the windows photo viewer DLL files to try to tweak them, such as editing speed etc. Since this wasn't possible in the registry.

When opening the files in a program such as ILSpy or dotPeek, I get a message that looks like this:

> This file does not contain a managed assembly.

I'm rather new to reverse engineering things so could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here since the programs say it's a .NET Framework 4.5 application.

Comment: It means the dll was not made with `.net`

Comment: @ExtremeCoders is there any way to figure out what it was made with?

Comment: Scan it with a pe detection tool like *PeiD*, *ExeInfo Pe*, *Detect It Easy* etc.

Comment: What is the file name you're trying to decompile?

Comment: @ThomasW. "PhotoViewer.dll" It is located under C:\Program files\Windows Photo Viewer\ on a normal windows 7 OS

Answer (score 5):

The problem you face is quite common. A .NET application still loads many native DLLs. Most surprising for many people is that the .NET framework itself is native.

You can identify .NET DLLs in WinDbg using the `lm v` command. In case of a managed DLL it says:

```
0:008> lmv m MyApp
start    end        module name
10310000 10574000   MyApp(deferred)             
    Image path: C:\...\MyApp.exe
    Image name: MyApp.exe
    Has CLR image header, track-debug-data flag not set
    Timestamp:        Wed May 21 16:34:02 2014 (537CB95A)
...
```

Note the line `Has CLR image header` in the output. The .NET framework is also loaded in that process, but it is native and does not have such a line:

```
0:008> lmv m mscorwks
start    end        module name
79470000 79a1e000   mscorwks   (pdb symbols)          d:\...\mscorwks.pdb
    Loaded symbol image file: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorwks.dll
    Image path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorwks.dll
    Image name: mscorwks.dll
    Timestamp:        Tue Oct 22 03:06:42 2013 (5265CFA2)
...
```

There are good reasons to use native DLLs by a managed application:

- because it's already implemented and stable
- for performance reasons: maybe C++ was just faster (maybe not in your case, since you don't seem to be happy with the performance)

`PhotoViewer.dll` is a native DLL, even if dotPeek says "Platform: .Net Framework 4.5". This seems to be a bug, because it also reports .NET for `kernel32.dll`.

The properties `Assembly platform` and `Module Runtime` seem to be a bit inconsistent anyway. Here are some combinations I tried that caused results which at least would need some explanation:

- kernel32: Platform 4.5, Runtime: none
- Jigfdt.fdt100: Platform 2.0, Runtime: 1.1.4322
- Fdt.ProfibusTransformers: Platform 4.0, Runtime 2.0.50727

Another way of detecting .NET is [Dependency Walker](http://dependencywalker.com/). A pure .NET assembly typically has only one dependency on `mscoree.dll` while native DLLs depend on different things.

Comment: how do get the `lmv` command to work? I have downloaded the windows debugging tools, but no success.

Comment: @kajacx: maybe you have .NET 4, Silverlight or .NET Core? Try `lmv m clr` and `lmv m coreclr`. If nothing works, try `lmv` on its own. If that does not work either, let me know more details about your environment. Are you doing live debugging or do you have a crash dump file?

Comment: @TomasWeller I don't know what half of these questions mean, I just wanted to decompile a .exe file to C# code, but now I have solved the problem in another way. Just out of curiosity, where do you even put the `lmv` commad? `0:008> lmv m MyApp` doesn't look like standard command line.

Comment: @kajacx: it seems you're quite unfamiliar with the topic. `0:008>` is a [WinDbg](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551063(v=vs.85).aspx) prompt. You can't decompile all programs to C# code. It must be written in .NET to do that.

Comment: Ok, so what to do when you get the message in OP?

Comment: @not2qubit: if it's not .NET, then do not use a .NET tool. Use a tool which is capable of decompiling native code, e.g. IDAPro, WinDbg, ...

Answer (score 3):

It's probably a native dll. You can probably decompile the main photo viewer binary (which presumably is managed code, based on your statement) to get some information about the native dll to assist in your disassembly based reverse engineering of the dll.

Answer (score 1):

If your dll is native, and is less than 10 MegaBytes in size, then try to use this [Retargetable decompiler](https://retdec.com/).